# Why do different approaches to per-feature differences in sf cause different plot zoom?

Tags: r, r-sf

I feel as though I lack the intuition to always know how `sf` objects will interact with `tidyverse` tools, especially `dplyr`. Here is an example. We're looking to take two buffers of points, and then subtract the smaller buffer, to leave a ring/annulus around each point. I provide two methods of doing it.

The first breaks off the geometry column, uses `map2` to get the annuli, and then bolts it back onto the original `sf` dataframe. This approach makes sense; I know how all the pieces work, but does not feel "tidy" or neat because we create intermediary objects, we have to manually replace the `crs`, and it feels as though it would be easy to mismatch geometries to attributes.

The second approach is what I came up with trying to keep it within a single pipe. Here I'm hoping that `group_by` and `mutate` can It does work, sort of, managing at least to run without error and seems to create the right annuli, but something causes the plot method to zoom in far. I also don't know if there are any other differences in what the two approaches actually do.

EDIT: It's not just plot zoom that is different, the result of `st_bbox` is also different for some reason. However, the rings still seem to be centered on the points, and they look the same in `mapview::mapview()`. Also included session info, I'm updated to R 3.4.4, `sf` 0.6-1, `tidyverse` 1.2.1. I'll update everything else though and see what happens.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, proj.4 4.9.3
set.seed(12345)
points = map2(runif(50, -10, 10), runif(50, -10, 10), ~ st_point(c(.x, .y))) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>%
  st_transform(3857)
sf_pts = st_sf(val = 1:50, geometry = points)

ring1 = st_buffer(points, 50000)
ring2 = st_buffer(points, 100000)
sep_rings = st_sfc(map2(ring2, ring1, ~ st_difference(.x, .y)), crs = 3857)
sf_opt1 <- sf_pts %>%
  st_set_geometry(sep_rings)
plot(sf_opt1)
```

[image]

```r
plot(sf_opt1$geometry)
plot(sf_pts$geometry, add = T)
```

[image]

```r
sf_opt2 <- sf_pts %>%
  mutate(
    ring1 = st_buffer(geometry, 50000),
    ring2 = st_buffer(geometry, 100000)
    ) %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(geometry = st_difference(ring2, ring1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(val)
plot(sf_opt2)
```

[image]

```r
plot(sf_opt2$geometry)
plot(sf_pts$geometry, add = T)
```

[image]

```r
st_bbox(sf_opt1)
#>     xmin     ymin     xmax     ymax 
#> -1210664 -1199345  1190345  1187217
st_bbox(sf_opt2)
#>      xmin      ymin      xmax      ymax 
#>  391818.2  938652.3  591818.2 1138652.3
```

Created on 2018-04-10 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> Session info -------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  tz       America/Los_Angeles         
#>  date     2018-04-10
#> Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package    * version    date       source                            
#>  assertthat   0.2.0      2017-04-11 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  backports    1.1.2      2017-12-13 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  base       * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  bindr        0.1.1      2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  bindrcpp   * 0.2        2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  broom        0.4.3      2017-11-20 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  cellranger   1.1.0      2016-07-27 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  class        7.3-14     2015-08-30 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  classInt     0.1-24     2017-04-16 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  cli          1.0.0      2017-11-05 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  colorspace   1.3-2      2016-12-14 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  compiler     3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  crayon       1.3.4      2017-09-16 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  curl         3.1        2017-12-12 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  datasets   * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  DBI          0.8        2018-03-02 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  devtools     1.13.5     2018-02-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  digest       0.6.15     2018-01-28 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  dplyr      * 0.7.4      2017-09-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  e1071        1.6-8      2017-02-02 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  evaluate     0.10.1     2017-06-24 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  forcats    * 0.3.0      2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  foreign      0.8-69     2017-06-22 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  ggplot2    * 2.2.1.9000 2018-03-28 Github (tidyverse/ggplot2@3c9c504)
#>  glue         1.2.0      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  graphics   * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  grDevices  * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  grid         3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  gtable       0.2.0      2016-02-26 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  haven        1.1.1      2018-01-18 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  hms          0.4.2      2018-03-10 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  htmltools    0.3.6      2017-04-28 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  httr         1.3.1      2017-08-20 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  jsonlite     1.5        2017-06-01 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  knitr        1.20       2018-02-20 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  lattice      0.20-35    2017-03-25 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  lazyeval     0.2.1      2017-10-29 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  lubridate    1.7.2      2018-02-06 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  magrittr     1.5        2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  memoise      1.1.0      2017-04-21 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  methods    * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  mime         0.5        2016-07-07 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  mnormt       1.5-5      2016-10-15 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  modelr       0.1.1      2017-07-24 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  munsell      0.4.3      2016-02-13 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  nlme         3.1-131.1  2018-02-16 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  parallel     3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  pillar       1.2.1      2018-02-27 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  pkgconfig    2.0.1      2017-03-21 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  plyr         1.8.4      2016-06-08 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  psych        1.7.8      2017-09-09 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  purrr      * 0.2.4      2017-10-18 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  R6           2.2.2      2017-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  Rcpp         0.12.16    2018-03-13 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  readr      * 1.1.1      2017-05-16 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  readxl       1.0.0      2017-04-18 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  reshape2     1.4.3      2017-12-11 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  rlang        0.2.0.9001 2018-03-26 Github (r-lib/rlang@49d7a34)      
#>  rmarkdown    1.9        2018-03-01 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  rprojroot    1.3-2      2018-01-03 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  rvest        0.3.2      2016-06-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  scales       0.5.0.9000 2018-01-23 Github (hadley/scales@d767915)    
#>  sf         * 0.6-1      2018-03-22 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  stats      * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  stringi      1.1.7      2018-03-12 CRAN (R 3.4.4)                    
#>  stringr    * 1.3.0      2018-02-19 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  tibble     * 1.4.2      2018-01-22 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  tidyr      * 0.8.0      2018-01-29 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  tidyverse  * 1.2.1      2017-11-14 CRAN (R 3.4.2)                    
#>  tools        3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  udunits2     0.13       2016-11-17 CRAN (R 3.4.1)                    
#>  units        0.5-1      2018-01-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  utils      * 3.4.4      2018-03-15 local                             
#>  withr        2.1.2      2018-03-26 Github (jimhester/withr@79d7b0d)  
#>  xml2         1.2.0      2018-01-24 CRAN (R 3.4.3)                    
#>  yaml         2.1.18     2018-03-08 CRAN (R 3.4.3)
```

Comment: I ran your code and got the same (expected) plot for both. Are your packages up to date?

Comment: I'm updated to R 3.4.4, sf 0.6-1, tidyverse 1.2.1. Will update everything and see what happens though

Comment: Everything is up to date now, but still getting this error. Should I move to the github? Not sure how to get it reproduced (got the same behaviour on a coworker's Mac as well)

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. It seems indeed to be only a bounding box problem. The polygons are identical with both approaches. If you plot first your points and then add the polygons to the plot you obtain hte same result. Maybe updating the bounding box of the second approach result could solve the problem but I don't know how (and anyway it is strange that the bounding box is changed like that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, in your example, you are essentially writing a loop over every row (group/ungroup around the mutate); by overwriting geometry within this loop, you get the bounding box of the last feature, rather than of the whole geometry list-column. The problem is that st_difference does all pairwise differences, rather than row-wise. You can get row-wise difference with the following code (which requires sf from github):

```
sf_opt2 <- sf_pts %>%
  mutate(
    ring1 = st_buffer(geometry, 50000),
    ring2 = st_buffer(geometry, 100000)
  ) %>%
  mutate(geometry = ring2 / ring1) %>%
  select(val)
plot(sf_opt2)
```

Comment: Awesome and thank you -  I saw the `/` notation commit but didn't realise it wasn't just an alias for `st_difference`. I guess it is here to stay and the affine transformations will change?